# Get quantity of product's categories via Order table

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

Looking for help with query. How can I count orders from specific product's category. I wrote for this moment query for all orders:

```
$total_orders = Order::where('orders.created_at', '>=', '2021-06-01')->join('transactions','order_id','orders.id')->where('status', 1)->count();
```

My relationship is:
Category 1:N Product (category_id)
Product 1:N Order (product_id)

Comment: Could you explain what goes wrong with your current query?

Comment: You mean to get the count of `Orders` which have products with particular `category_id`?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you mistyped a table name in your join. Check this please:

```
$total_orders = Order::where('orders.created_at', '>=', '2021-06-01')->join('transactions','transactions.order_id', '=', 'orders.id')->where('orders.status', 1)->count();
```